# samba share in /etc/fstab is ignored during mount -a but manual mount works

Tags: ubuntu, samba, mount, fstab

It's one of these problems I'm running into every time that I set up a server :-(
I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 and would like to auto-mount a samba share.

In my /etc/fstab I have the entry:

```
//10.10.2.2/share    /media/share    cifs    defaults,_netdev,noauto,nofail,username=user,passwd=pass    0    0
```

When I execute

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get no error message but the share is not mounted :-(

The most interesting part however is that if I do a

```
sudo mount /media/share
```

The share is mounted

I had various problems with samba before but this behavior is new for me. Does anybody have an idea how to address this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's normal behaviour if you set `noauto`. From `man mount`:

> **noauto** Can  only  be  mounted  explicitly (i.e., the **-a** option will not
>                 cause the filesystem to be mounted).

Comment: Oh f**ck. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing me to this option (that I just copied from an old server).